# Where does The Fractured But Whole keep save files?

Tags: south-park-the-fractured-but-whole

I want to do a fresh install of Windows 8, but I'm about eight hours in to the new South Park game.

Any ideas on where the game keeps its save files? I looked in `Documents/MyGames/SouthPark - The Fractured But Whole/` but I don't see anything labeled a 'save file'.

Comment: Have you tried looking in AppData?

Answer (score 5):

`C:\Users\Public\Documents\uPlay\[your account]\Saves\SouthParkTFBW\`

I had to look through my anti virus scanner protocol while runnging the game

Comment: Is the carater saved as well in that save file